# Shorter syntax for context bounds?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to use shorter syntax when using context-bound type parameters? At the moment I have something like this

```
case class Vector2D[a : Numeric](x: a, y: a) {
  val numA = implicitly[Numeric[a]]

  def length2 = numA.plus(numA.times(x, x), numA.times(y, y))
}
```

and it makes more complex formulae unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this REPL session:

```
scala>  case class Vector2D[T : Numeric](x: T, y: T) {
  val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  import numeric._
  def length2 = (x*x)+(y*y)
}

defined class Vector2D

scala> Vector2D(3,4).length2
res0: Int = 25
```

This is because Numeric contains an implicit conversion called mkNumericOps which you can import as shown above. If it didn't come out of the box, the way you could roll this yourself would be something like:

```
scala> implicit class NumericOps[T](val x: T) extends AnyVal { def +(y: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]): T = n.plus(x, y)
     | def *(y: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]): T = n.times(x, y)
     | }
defined class NumericOps

scala> case class Vector2D[a : Numeric](x: a, y: a) { def length2 = (x*x)+(y*y) }
defined class Vector2D

scala> Vector2D(3,4).length2
res0: Int = 25
```

If you make `NumericOps` not a value class (don't extend AnyVal) then the implicit Numeric can go on the constructor instead of each method, which might be better, or not really matter.

Anyway there's no need to write your own since Numeric already has `mkNumericOps`.

These "ops" classes are called the "enrich my library" pattern.

`Numeric.Ops` is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric$Ops)
and the implicit being imported to auto-create it is `mkNumericOps` on Numeric, [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric).

Comment: You don't need the `val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[T]]` line, you never use it.

Comment: it's used on the next line? `import numeric._`

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
```

then for every type that for which an implicit Numeric can be found

(importing just the NumericOps conversion of one Numeric instance as suggested by @Havoc P gives you finer control as to for which types operations are available, but most of the time, `Numeric.Implicits` should be fine)

On the more general question is there a shorter syntax when using context bounds type parameters: in general, there is not. It is up to the typeclass to provide some sugar to make it easy to use, as Numeric does here.

For instance, it is more or less customary to have an apply method in the companion object which makes getting the instance a little easier than with implicitly

```
object Ordering {
   def apply[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Ordering[T] = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
}
```

so that you can get the implicit just with e.g `Ordering[Int]`, rather than `implicitly[Ordering[Int]]`.